# WebSocket is rarely able to sends data ) but receives everytime

Tags: javascript, c#, sockets, websocket

The handshaking is successful and webSocket.onopen is also being called. When I send data from server (C#) to client (chrome, js) it all goes well but when I try to send data from client to the server mostly no data is received and there is not error message on either side. First I thought that this would be because of my custom methods of accepting data but that does not seem to be the case because socket.Avaliable also returns that no data is available (even thought client side show it's sent). Tell me if the server code is needed but here is my client side. The method initialiseClient is called as soon as the page finishes loading and send message is called inside a onConnectListener's listener:

```js
    /*Events*/

var onConnectListeners = [];
var onRecieveListeners = [];
var onDisconnectListeners = [];

function addConnectListener(listener)
{
 onConnectListeners.push(listener);
}

function addRecieveListener(listener)
{
 onRecieveListeners.push(listener);
}

function addDisconnectListener(listener)
{
 onDisconnectListeners.push(listener);
}

function removeRecieveListener(listener)
{
 onRecieveListeners.splice(onRecieveListeners.indexOf(listener));
}

function removeDisconnectListener(listener)
{
 onDisconnectListeners.splice(onDisconnectListeners.indexOf(listener));
}

function removeConnectListener(listener)
{
 onConnectListeners.splice(onConnectListeners.indexOf(listener));
}

/*Variables*/

var socket;

/*Initialisation*/

function initialiseClient(serverIP)
{
 socket = new WebSocket(serverIP);
 socket.onopen = onConnect;
 socket.onmessage = onMessage;
 socket.onclose = onDisconnect;
 
}

/*Socket Event Listeners*/

function onConnect()
{
 for(var i = 0; i < onConnectListeners.length; i++)
  onConnectListeners[i]();
}

function onDisconnect()
{
 for(var i = 0; i < onDisconnectListeners.length; i++)
  onDisconnectListeners[i]();
}

function onMessage(message)
{
 console.log("MESSAGE: " + message);
 for(var i = 0; i < onRecieveListeners.length; i++)
  onRecieveListeners[i](message);
}

/*Sending*/

function send(data)
{
 socket.send(data);
}
```

Here is a screenshot: [The message is sent thousands of time but received only a few times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXCPs.png)

On a side node: Did you notice the text received is always different (though this can be a problem in my own code but I cannot be sure until I figure out the main issue)

Edit: I found the issue! On the server side when I was accepting clients I was adding them to a list and when accepting was complete I called the callback provided (that did the handshake) but I was not removing the item from the list. As a result every time the action complete the handshake code was called that accepted that data and therefore leaving not data for me to receive.

OLD: `while (node != null)
            {
                if (node.Value.Task.IsCompleted)
                {
                    if (node.Value.Task.IsFaulted || node.Value.Task.IsCanceled)
                        Console.Log("Failed!");
                    else
                        Utilities.Handshake(node.Value.Task.Result);
                node = nextNode;
            }`

Just needed to added:
    'node.List.Remove(node);'
 and it worked!

Comment: It's almost impossible to use JS websocket implementation incorrectly. Please attach the server code as well.

Comment: @Vovanrock2002 you were right and I managed to solve the issue! Edited the question with the solution!

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Comment: Thanks! It was one of the hardest bug for me to solve,